# What is this figure I have obtained from this MATLAB code around Earth-Moon Lagrange point 2?

Tags: interplanetary, lagrangian-points, low-energy-transfer

This is part of the code I used, where EM: Earth moon

```
K= (1-mu_EM)/d2^3 + mu_EM/r2^3;
alpha= 1- 0.5*K;
beta= (2*K+1)*(K-1);
s= sqrt(alpha+sqrt(alpha^2+beta^2));
v= (s^2+2*K+1)/2*s;

t= (0:5);
x= [x_0*cos(s*t)];
y= [x_0*v*sin(s*t)];
plot(x,y)
```

%where x0= 0.75 and y0=0;

Output:

[image: output of above code]

and this after re-iterations

[image: output of above code with t=(0:48)]

Comment: I think the step size of t is too small to make a meaningful plot

Comment: you need much, much smaller `t`. use `t = (0:1e-6:5)` instead

Comment: Looks interesting, what are $d2$ and $r2$? Can you add those so that others can reproduce your result? Thanks! and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: d1= sqrt((LEM1(1)/r_EM+mu_EM)^2);
r1= sqrt((LEM1(1)/r_EM-1+mu_EM)^2); , where L_EM(1) is vpa("321719.8302135080542892580194048")

Comment: @AntonHengst it does show an elliptical graph using smaller intervals, but still difficult to interpret it

Comment: mind sharing it?